# Is there a way to copy code to another page by itself?

Tags: javascript, html, automation

I'm sure I didn't describe it right, but basically I have a large list of my art that i have to manually copy to  each page the art appears on. Hopefully i can make it more understandable below.

The website is https://carrigan.netlify.com is my website that im building to house all HQ pieces of my art.
For the [2020 page](https://carrigan.netlify.app/portfolio/2020/), i copy-paste the same thing for every piece (im sure theres a better way but thats for another time)

```
<img class="myImg" src="../art/2020/MTA2020.png" alt= "2020's Meet The Artist - Personal - Jan 14, 2020" style="height:100%; max-height:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="../art/2020/JordanBday2020.png" alt= "Purchase of a Lone God - Gift - Feb 19, 2020" style="height:100%; max-height:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="../art/2020/Fired.PNG" alt= "You're Fired - Gift - March 5, 2020" style="height:100%; max-height:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="../art/2020/Fired2.PNG" alt= "You're Fired (Alt) - Gift - March 5, 2020" style="height:100%; max-height:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="../art/2020/Chara.PNG" alt= " A Genocidal Freak - Undertale Fanart - March 27, 2020" style="height:100%; max-height:300px">
<img class="myImg" src="../art/2020/Gidjet.PNG" alt= "Space Mechanic On Sight! - Gift - April 8, 2020" style="height:100%; max-height:300px">
etc
```

but in order to get it on my [portfolio page](https://carrigan.netlify.app/portfolio/complete/) i have to just copy the large blocks of text to the other index.html.

is there any way to make it auto-update to have it add to the complete page every time i add a new one?

Comment: You can use XHR to get data from your server. Create some JSON file or database with all your images for each year. When user load a page, it automatically request that JSON file where will be all URLs, alts (or some labels) and then just create new images (and labels) in JavaScript and place them into a page.